# How to unserialize the JSON data in server part

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, jquery-events

I have a simple form which I try to post using jQuery post in JSON format. The form is getting post but my problem is at PHP part. I am unable to get the data. From other stack question I found solution of just doing `$_POST['FirstName']` but I am getting result as `"FirstName=john&LastName=plar&Address=home&PhoneNumber=23423423".`

How can I decode this JSON data? Below are the code that I have tried so far. Thank you.

```
<form action="user.php" method="post" id="myForm">
    First Name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" />
    Last Name: <input type="text" name="LastName" />
    Address: <input type="text" name="Address" />
    Phone: <input type="text" name="PhoneNumber" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/> 
</form>

<script>
$("#submit").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $("#myForm input").serialize();
    $.post('user.php',{"data":JSON.stringify(data)},function(data){

    },'json');

})
</script>
```

user.php

```
$object =$_POST['data'];
$array = json_decode($object);
print_r($object);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use JSON at all, just [serialize and upload](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) the form.

```
$("#submit").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post(
        'user.php',
        $("#myForm").serialize(),
        function(data, textStatus){
            // do stuff with the response
        }
    );
});
```

Then in your PHP

```
<?php
echo $_POST["FirstName"];
// etc
```

Comment: when I tried your method, it is working fine. But when I use
var data = $("#myForm").serialize();
   $.post('user.php',{'data':data},function(data){ }); why its not working.

Comment: Because that's not how to submit a form! You're trying to pass a serialized form as a string.

Answer (score 1):

you can make some changes in your script and PHP code to get a native $_POST data that don't need to unserialize:

Change script to make data posted is only your serialized form:

```
$("#submit").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post('user.php',{$("#myForm").serialize()},function(data){});
});
```

And in your PHP code, just dump your $_POST variable:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

And you can get this result:

```
array(4) {
  ["FirstName"]=>
  string(7) "b j hhj"
  ["LastName"]=>
  string(7) "bhjbhj "
  ["Address"]=>
  string(5) "jhjjh"
  ["PhoneNumber"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

This will efficient than serialize & unserialize many time.